# How to Make 4 cells in each line by only css & html

Tags: html, css

What I want to inquire about him, how to make 4 cells in each line automatically without the use of programming languages ​​such as php .
In other words, I want the line is not likely more than 4 cells and any new cell to be in a new line automatically, without manually to put in the code `<tr>`

Comment: If you want four cells per row *put four cells (`<td>`) in the row (`<tr>`)*. Where are you stuck?

Comment: So i wrote `without manually to put in the code <tr>`

Comment: Well, this can't be done with [tag:css], or without a programming language. So which constraint are you prepared to give up?

Comment: i have a Variable is repeated , I want to come every one of them in a cell, and the 4 cells are in a single line only , can not use `width` or any thing to do that without `php`

Comment: Please show the current html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a table markup like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
        <td>Cell 5</td>
        <td>Cell 6</td>
        <td>Cell 7</td>
        <td>Cell 8</td>
        <td>Cell 9</td>
        <td>Cell 10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...You can cause each row to have 4 cells with the following css:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Xjam7/1/)**

### CSS

```
td {
    float: left;
}
td:nth-child(4n + 5) {
    clear:left;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want the each `td` to take up 25% of the table width, then you'll need you set a width on your table and then set `width: 25%` on all `td` elements (also reset defalt margin/paddings to 0)

Like so:

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Xjam7/2/)**

```
body, td {
    margin: 0;padding:0;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
td {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Question, what if I want to give every `<td>` width `25%` ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> Cell 1 </td>
  <td> Cell 2 </td>
  <td> Cell 3 </td>
  <td> Cell 4 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This is the HTML

Comment: yeah i know it already, but when i own 10 cells i want them Automatically split into 4 cells in each line , how ?

Comment: AH okay I see, this cannot be done with pure HTML and CSS as far as I know. Will require a bit of javascript

Comment: IE there is no attribute called `maximum_cells` or anything

Comment: well , i don't know much about java :(

Comment: yeah i mean java-script

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to create a layout for a page and you use `<tr>` as a synonym for *line/row* of blocks, not for creating layout tables made of `table`, `tr` and `td` ([that's a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)) or worse here for data table (a data table with 4 cells per row also have 4 header cells `th` in the first row (in general) and do use `tr` to semantically indicate where the rows are and how much cells they each contain)

That said, you can use sibling elements in your HTML code and float them. Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8tz2/)**

Relevant code:

HTML

```
<div class="block">Some content 1</div>
<div class="block">Some content 2</div>
<!-- (...) -->
```

CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    width: 400px;
}
.block {
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0 1% 1% 0;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

/* Improvements for last "row" http://slides.com/heydon/effortless-style#/45 and next slides */
.block:nth-child(4n+1):last-child {
    width: 99%;
}
.block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(2),
.block:nth-child(4n+2):last-child {
    width: 49%;
}
.block:nth-child(4n+1):nth-last-child(3),
.block:nth-child(4n+2):nth-last-child(2),
.block:nth-child(4n+3):last-child {
    width: 32%;
}
```

Comment: thnx for your work , i found simple code and working as i want